# excel vba copying fedex tracking information

Tags: excel, vba, dom, web-scraping

I want to copy into Excel 3 tracking information tables that [website](https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/index.html?tracknumbers=713418602663&cntry_code=us) generates when I track a parcel. I want to do it through Excel VBA. I can write a loop and generate this webpage for various tracking numbers. But I am having a hard time copying tables - the top table, travel history and shipments track table. Any solution? In my vba code last 3 lines below are giving an error :( - run time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or error.

```
Sub final()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
my_url = "https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/index.html?tracknumbers=713418602663&cntry_code=us"

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate my_url


    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    End With

ie.document.getElementById("detailsBody").Value
ie.document.getElementById("trackLayout").Value 
ie.document.getElementById("detail").Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Value` is not a method available in that context. also, you will want to assign the return value of the method call to a variable. Also, you should declare your variables :)

I made some modifications and include one possible way of getting data from one of the tables. YOu may need to reformat the output using TextToColumns or similar, since it prints each row in a single cell.

I also notice that when I execute this, the tables have sometimes not finished loading and the result will be an error unless you put in a suitable `Wait` or use some other method to determine when the data has fully loaded on the webpage.  I use a simple `Application.Wait`

```
Option Explicit

Sub final()
Dim ie As Object
Dim my_url As String
Dim travelHistory As Object
Dim history As Variant
Dim h As Variant
Dim i As Long



Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
my_url = "https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/index.html?tracknumbers=713418602663&cntry_code=us"


    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate my_url
        '## I modified this logice a little bit:
        Do While .Busy And .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

    End With

'## Here is a simple method wait for IE to finish, you may need a more robust solution
'   For assistance with that, please ask a NEW question.

Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("0:00:10")


'## Get one of the tables
Set travelHistory = ie.Document.GetElementByID("travel-history")
'## Split teh table to an array
history = Split(travelHistory.innerText, vbLf)
'## Iterate the array and write each row to the worksheet
For Each h In history
    Range("A1").Offset(i).Value = h
    i = i + 1
Next


ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: how can i copy content of those tables into excel? Would it be possible to modify your code to show how to paste data into excel "Sheet1" column A, B and C?

Comment: The code you have provided does not actually capture the contents of the tables. I will see if there's a quick fix for that. In the meantime since this has solved the immediate problem of `438` error, please consider upvoting this answer.

Comment: See revision which shows one simple method of extracting the table's data. You will likely need to fine-tune this for formatting. Questions regarding that should be a new question, please :)